# Advice regarding best-practice mathematics / categorial logic.

Tags: reference-request, logic, category-theory, self-learning, advice

A good heuristic is:

> If it doesn't cost anything, generalize.

In particular, if we have

- a theorem, and
- a proof thereof,

then we ought to look for a maximal generalization of this theorem, subject to the constraint: "the basic ideas of the original proof can be used to manufacture a proof of the generalization."

I do my best to abide by this heuristic, since I regard it as "best-practice."

However, its lately occurred to me that I've been failing to heed this heuristic. **Bigtime.** The basic reason is category theory / categorial semantics.

Let me explain. Its well known that we may consider models of a signature in any category possessing sufficient structure. Thus, set-theoretic models are just a special case. Furthermore, the internal logic of different categories is different. Therefore:

> We should prove things not only under minimal hypotheses; but also, in the weakest possible logic.

However:

**I tend to prove things by assuming an internal logic that is classical.** For example, I will say something like the following. Let $G$ denote a model of Group. Then [insert argument here]. We conclude that $G$ satisfies $\varphi$. Thus, $\varphi$ is a classical theorem of Group.

The problem is that typically, only a weak fragment of classical first-order logic was actually needed to state and/or prove $\varphi$. Thus, the conclusion "$\varphi$ is a classical theorem of Group" is a far cry from being maximally general.

So here's, a little summary.

**I want to produce well-conceptualized, maximally general, best-practice mathematics. My ignorance of categorial logic is getting in the way. In the short term, what should I do?**

The medium-to-long term solution, of course, is to actually learn categorial logic! And frankly, I'm *trying*. But progress is slow, and I don't really have a good resource to learn it from. So, my next question is

**2. Given my specific concerns and interests, what would be a good resource for learning this stuff?**

Furthermore:

**3. Should I just pick a book and work through it, problem-by-problem? Is there a better way to learn this material?**

Thank you, and your time is appreciated.

Comment: [This might interest you.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53188/decent-texts-on-categorical-logic)

Comment: @Shaun, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the answer depend strongly on what do you already know.

If you already have a good confidence with lots of advanced category theory you could run through Johnstone "Sketches of an Elephant".

Then there's another text book: McLarty "Elementary categories, elementary toposes".

Another reference that I've used to learn topos theory is [Barr and Wells' "Topos, Triples and Theories"](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/12/tr12abs.html) which can be downloaded from the link.

All these references have as main aim toposes and so most of the material is about categorical logic in a topos. Nonetheless Johnstone and Barr&Well's book have some material about cartesian closed categories (and so algebraic theories), coherent categories and so on.

Of course these books require that the reader have a previous knowledge of category theory and feel quite confident with most of the *basic construction* of category theory.
In case you lack of this knowledge I suggest you take a look to Awodey's book "Category Theory", which is one of the best introductory book in category theory which also have a logical flavour (at least in my personal opinion).
Then you can take a look to Bourceux book to learn some more advanced category theory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As an introductory book on topos with categorical logic as a goal, I would add *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* by MacLane and Moerdijk.